# Run a bash command until another command returns no output

Tags: bash, xml

How can I make a command run in a while loop until another command returns no output? 
I want this command:

```
wget https://example.com/example.xml
```

to run until this command:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//POST[100]/@id)' example.xml
```

returns an output containing nothing because `example.xml` would no longer contain the `id` attribute in the `<POST>` tag, causing

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//POST[100]/@id)' temporary.download
```

to return no output.

Any ideas or tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than "no output", could you check the exit status of `xmllint` (`$?`)? Read `man xmllint`.

Comment: I already tried this. When there is no output, the exit status is still 0.